# Vue highchart how to set language

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I'm using the [highchart-vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue) and I want to set the language to German. How can I do that?

I tried this on the component directly:

```
<script>

import { Chart } from 'highcharts-vue';

Chart.setOptions({
  lang: {
    months: [
      'Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April',
      'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August',
      'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'
    ]
  },   
})

export default {
   components: {
      highcharts: Chart
   },
...
}

</script>
```

but that doesn't work.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you try the answer?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
    import { Chart } from 'highcharts-vue';
    import Highcharts from "highcharts";
    
    Highcharts.setOptions({
      lang: {
        months: [
          'Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April',
          'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August',
          'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'
        ]
      }
    })

    export default {
        components: {
             highcharts: Chart
        },
     ...
    }
```